# How I get the substring?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, web

how can I get the substring of the string:

```
[{
  "ProductId"=>198, 
  "AttributesXml"=>"<Attributes><ProductAttribute ID=\"590\"><ProductAttributeValue><Value>1691</Value></ProductAttributeValue></ProductAttribute></Attributes>",   
  "StockQuantity"=>1, 
  "AllowOutOfStockOrders"=>false,
  "Sku"=>nil, 
  "ManufacturerPartNumber"=>nil, 
  "Gtin"=>nil, 
  "OverriddenPrice"=>nil, 
  "NotifyAdminForQuantityBelow"=>1, "Id"=>1756
  },
```

I want only the value of `"ProductAtrribute ID": 590`. Only the number.
I have checked out the ruby docs, but I cannot find a solution.

Comment: Where does `590 ` come from?

Comment: Can you update this question with the full string representation of the data you are working with and use code formatting to help us read it?

Comment: Sorry, I edited my post. The 590 is in the string.

Comment: NP - thanks for the clarification, what do you have so far? Can you post that as well?

Comment: We'd like to see what you tried. Without evidence of effort it looks like you want us to solve it for you, which is not what SO is for. Which docs did you read and why didn't they help? Did you write code? If not, why? If so, where is the minimum code demonstrating the problem?

Comment: You're working with a horrible quasi-XML format. Do you have any control over it?

Answer (score 3):

The tag has rails, if you are in rails then you can leverage nokogiri gem to handle parsing the AttributesXml section:

```
require 'nokogiri'

array = [{"ProductId"=>198, "AttributesXml"=>"<Attributes><ProductAttribute
 ID=\"590\"><ProductAttributeValue><Value>1691</Value>
 </ProductAttributeValue></ProductAttribute></Attributes>",
 "StockQuantity"=>1, "AllowOutOfStockOrders"=>false,"Sku"=>nil,
 "ManufacturerPartNumber"=>nil, "Gtin"=>nil, "OverriddenPrice"=>nil,
 "NotifyAdminForQuantityBelow"=>1, "Id"=>1756}]

array.each do |item|
  doc = Nokogiri::XML(item['AttributesXml'])
  puts doc.xpath("//ProductAttribute").attribute('ID')
end
=> 590
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I get these error: "no implicit conversion of String into Integer" at this point: "doc = Nokogiri::XML(test['AttributesXml'])"

Comment: what can I do? Can you help me please?

Comment: Its because you must be in an array. put this in a `each` loop. Updated answer and put the test data into an array. The general idea is that you should be able to use more common ruby operators to fix up the results the way you need after we've shown you how to extract the data out of the XML string.

Comment: I dont understand you. Can you give me an example please?

Comment: Be careful using `doc.xpath("//ProductAttribute").attribute('ID')`. `xpath` returns a NodeSet so `attribute` would return an array if multiple `ProductAttribute` nodes were found.

Answer (score 1):

I'd use:

```
require 'nokogiri'

foo = [
  {
    "ProductId"=>198, 
    "AttributesXml"=>"<Attributes><ProductAttribute ID=\"590\"><ProductAttributeValue><Value>1691</Value></ProductAttributeValue></ProductAttribute></Attributes>",   
    "StockQuantity"=>1, 
    "AllowOutOfStockOrders"=>false,
    "Sku"=>nil, 
    "ManufacturerPartNumber"=>nil, 
    "Gtin"=>nil, 
    "OverriddenPrice"=>nil, 
    "NotifyAdminForQuantityBelow"=>1, "Id"=>1756
  },
]

foo.map { |hash|
  Nokogiri::XML(hash['AttributesXml']).at('ProductAttribute')['ID']
}
# => ["590"]
```

It'll return the ID from all `<ProductAttribute>` nodes in all the hashes in the array.

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of [**`scan`**](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-scan)

```
array = [{"ProductId"=>198, "AttributesXml"=>"<Attributes>
  <ProductAttribute  
  ID=\"590\"><ProductAttributeValue><Value>1691</Value>
  </ProductAttributeValue></ProductAttribute></Attributes>",   
  "StockQuantity"=>1, "AllowOutOfStockOrders"=>false,""Sku"=>nil, 
  "ManufacturerPartNumber"=>nil, "Gtin"=>nil, "OverriddenPrice"=>nil, 
  "NotifyAdminForQuantityBelow"=>1, "Id"=>1756},.. ]
```

and

```
array.each do |hash| 
  hash["AttributesXml"].scan(/ProductAttribute\s+ID=\"(\d+)\"/).flatten
  #=> ["590"]
  # This will return matched values
end
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. it works perfect. but how can I get only the number? I get ["590"]. And how can I get only the first one?

Comment: I get ["590"] ["590"] ["590"] ["590"] ["590"] . I want only one 590.